# Angular Refresh View After Adding Item to Array- better way?

Tags: angular, primeng

Using Angular 11.2.14:  I have a object with a object array property "Ticket_Notes" that is used to populate a PrimeNG Timeline object, nothing special:

```
            <p-timeline [value]="ticket.Ticket_Notes" align="alternate">
            <ng-template pTemplate="marker" let-note >
                <span class="custom-marker shadow-2" >
                    <img *ngIf="note.Created_ByNavigation?.Photo" alt="Person Photo" class="Photo" style="height:50px;" [src]="note.Created_ByNavigation?.Photo"/>
                </span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-note>
                <p-card [header]="note.Created_ByNavigation?.DisplayName" [subheader]="note.Creation_Date | date: 'medium'" >
                        <div class="contentStack">                                 
                            <div *ngIf="note.Resolved_Ticket"><i  class="fas fa-check fa-lg ok"></i>&nbsp;Ticket Resolved</div>                       
                            <div *ngIf="note.editComment">
                                <p-editor [(ngModel)]="note.Note_Data" [style]="{'height':'125px'}"></p-editor>                                    
                            </div>    
                            <div [ngClass]="{'resolvedTicket': note.Resolved_Ticket}">                   
                                <div *ngIf="!note.editComment" [innerHTML]="note.Note_Data"></div>                                
                            </div> 
                        </div>                         
                </p-card>
            </ng-template>
            </p-timeline>
```

My issue is, if a push a new object into the array (after someone adds a note) - it will not display unless I deep clone the object with:

```
 this.ticket = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ticket)) // cheat to get it to reload/refresh view
```

Then it will appear just fine. This seems like a bad hack. Is there a better/best practice to get the page to refresh the view with the added item?

Comment: if we have onPush change detection then we need to give new reference to reflect the changes. We can do this for pushing the new object in array: this.ticket = [...this.ticket, newObject]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the reference by this:
this.ticket = [...this.ticket];

This should trigger a re-rendering.

Comment: This does in fact work. Is this the "normal" way? Is this what "normal" people do? lol I mean I guess normal is relative. Just wondering if I am missing some key concept of change detection.

Comment: When you use the default ChangeDetectionStrategy  (not OnPush), then the spread syntax [... ]. will return a new array. This is a common way (normal). For objects you can use {...obj}.    If you are using the OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy in your component, then you have to call detectChanges() on the injected service ChangeDetectorRef.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the info. Hard to tell when I am not following standard practice...